# Converting voltages using LM337

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator, dc-dc-converter, linear-regulator

I have 2 questions:
Is it possible to generate -35V from LM337 regulator with -12V in input??
The voltage output from LM337 is supposed to follow this equation, -Vout=-1.25(1+R2/R1)+Iadj.R2 but in ISIS simulation the output value is always the same as the input, I don't understand why, for example in the picture above output value is supposed to be -32V according to the resistances values but it is -39V because the input is -40V, the same for any other voltage.[image]

Comment: It's a *linear* regulator. You better understand it's limitations..

Comment: Warning - circuit error

Comment: Consider using a [boost converter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boost_converter). You have to understand that a linear converter basically converts excess voltage to heat, so they are only desirable for small voltage drops. The advantage is that the voltage they produce has almost no ripple in it.

Answer (score 6):

In your drawing, you have the voltage-set resistors connected incorrrectly.  R1 should be between Ourput and Adjust, and R2 from Adjust to Ground.

However, correcting this won't allow the LM337 to create a higher output voltage than its input voltage.

Linear regulators such as the LM317, LM78xx, LM337, LM79xx can only *reduce* the input voltage, not increase it.  It might have been clearer if they were originally called "Voltage Reducers" rather than "Voltage Regulators".  The regulators require some minimum voltage across them, called "Dropout Voltage" - 2 volts or more for many types, but "Low Dropout" regulators can work with less than 1 volt difference between input and output.

Answer (score 2):

No. The LM337 is a linear regulator. Internally there is a transistor *dropping or reducing* voltage between the input and the output. The voltage out will always be less than the voltage in.

Answer (score 2):

Input must be larger in magnitude than output by a couple volts. see the dropout specs. It is guaranteed with the input -3V or more from the output.

If you want -12V out you should feed it -15V or larger magnitude negative voltage.

With no load the output will generally track the output below the 'drop out', with a significant voltage drop (see below).

See this from the [datasheet](http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/LM337-D.PDF):

[image]